Как спарсить тесты с ответами с сайта fipi.ru
Хочу сделать телеграмм бота для учеников для подготовки к ЕГЭ. На сайте фипи есть открытая база вопросов, но ответы подгружаются динамически. Возможно ли их также спарсить. Ссылка на базу знаний https://ege.fipi.ru/bank/index.php?proj=068A227D253BA6C04D0C832387FD0D89. Благодарю за любой ответ.

Вы хотите сделать сайт с ответами сразу верными или как?... Не очень понимаю задачу и цель, которую вы хотите достичь.

Это будет телеграмм бот

На странице с заданиями нет ответов, это означает, что нельзя спарсить того, чего нет. Ответ берется (предположительно) из внутренней базы сайта. При нажатии на кнопку "Ответить" формируется POST-запрос, который возвращает ответ (верный или неверный). Можете сами изучить это через "Консоль разработчика".

Динамически подгружаемые данные можно спарсить, используя Playwright или Selenium
